# php sql where command to check for containg

Tags: php, sql

I get a string vaiable using POST in my php. I want to append this string so that i can use in the sql query to check for containing this string. I want something like this %string%

What i am doing now this gives me error:

```
$hotelName = '%'+hotelName_old+'%';
```

Comment: What's your query and what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this

$hotelName = "%'".$hotelName_old."'%";

Answer (score 1):

just to be sure: did you change your statement to ... WHERE fieldname **LIKE** '%value%'??

Comment: k i got the statement for php
    $hotelName = '%'.$hotelName.'%';
But how do i include this variable in my LIKE query

Answer (score 0):

try this.

just directly use your variable.

```
$sql = "select * from `tbl_name` where `field_name` like '%{$find}%'"
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```